# Did Kant and Satre have the same view on morality

Tags: ethics, kant

So in Kantian morality, in each act, you act as if your choice should become a universal law.  And in Existentialism and Humanism Satre says that in every choice you choose for all man.

Are they promoting the same sort of view, or are the similarities merely superficial?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Sartre imitate Kant in moral philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10550/does-sartre-imitate-kant-in-moral-philosophy)